# Unable to create AVD in android studio, windows

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create an AVD in Android Studio 3.0.1. using Windows 10.

Every time I create one it raises the following error:

> An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details.

My BIOS settings are also activated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do what the error says - Look into the idea.log file to try and get a solution

Comment: So, what errors are there in idea.log?....

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable virtualization in your BIOS.